# xr-hyper package and \includegraphics

Tags: includegraphics, xr

With the two following documents, I get a correct result: in the second document, the first chapter page from first document is included and the external link opens the correct page in the first document.

[image]

First document (`xr-ext.tex`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%\frontmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
Text of introduction....

%\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\label{myextref}
Text of first chapter...
\end{document}
```

Second document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\externaldocument{xr-ext}

\begin{document}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,page=\getpagerefnumber{myextref}]{xr-ext}}

Here, my reference to chapter \ref{myextref}.
\end{document}
```

But, if I use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` (the corresponding lines are commented in my first document), the `\getpagerefnumber` macro gives the logical page (1) and not the physical page (3) and the `\includegraphics` macro includes the "Introduction page" instead of the "First chapter" page (but the external links via `\ref` works).

[image]

Which macro of the `xr-hyper` package can I use to get the physical page of an external reference?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the zref-package. It stores absolute page numbers:

External document (test-utf8.tex):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-abspage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
Text of introduction....

\mainmatter
\chapter{First chapter}
\zlabel{myextref}
Text of first chapter...
\end{document}
```

Second document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{zref-user,zref-xr}
\makeatletter\let\zrefextractdefault\zref@extractdefault\makeatother 
\zexternaldocument{test-utf8}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\framebox{\includegraphics[width=5cm,
    page=\zrefextractdefault{myextref}{abspage}{1}]{test-utf8}}

Here, my reference to chapter \zref{myextref}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution but, here, the external document must be modified to use `\zlabel`....

Comment: Another problem: the `1` in second document is no longer a link to the external document.